# Closed subset of $C([0,1],\mathbb R$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $B=\{f\in C^1[0,1]:\Vert f\Vert _\infty \le A\}$. Is $B$ a closed subset of $C([0,1],\mathbb R)$?

Here's what I tried to do:

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequences of functions of $B$ such that $f_n \to f$, with $f\in C([0,1],\mathbb R)$.

If I prove that  $f\in B$, then I finish the proof, i.e. $B$ will be closed in  $C([0,1],\mathbb R)$.

But I don't know how could I do that.

Note:  $C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ is the space of continuous functions with domain $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B$ is not closed!

Let
$$f_{n} = \left\{\begin{matrix}
A(x-\frac{1}{2})^{{1+\frac{1}{n}}} &  x \in [\frac{1}{2},1]\\  
- A\left |x-\frac{1}{2}\right |^{{1+\frac{1}{n}}}   &     x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]
\end{matrix}\right.$$

then $\left \| f_{n} \right \|_{\infty} \leqslant A$ and $f_n$ is differentiable  at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n\in N$. Therefore $f_{n} \in B$ for all $n \in N$ .  It is easy to show that

$$f_{n} \rightarrow f= \left\{\begin{matrix}
A(x-\frac{1}{2})&  x \in [\frac{1}{2},1]\\  
- A\left |x-\frac{1}{2}\right |&     x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]
\end{matrix}\right.$$

but $f \in C[0,1] \setminus C^{1}[0,1]$, so $f \notin B.$

Answer (score 5):

Every continuous function on $[0,1]$ is a limit of a (bounded) sequence of polynomials (Weierstrass' theorem), so this set is not closed for any $A>0$. However, for $A= 0$ it is closed being a singleton.

Of course, you may pick your favourite example of a sequence of differentiable functions converging uniformly to a non-differentiable one and renormalise it suitably.

Comment: I don't see what Weierstrass' Theorem has to do with this set not being closed for $A>0$.

Comment: @kccu such sets are actually dense in the closed ball $B(0,A)$.

Comment: What "such sets"?

Comment: @kccu, the OP has in mind, namely $B$

Comment: AH I missed the little superscript $1$ in OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

Ahh, another simple example of sequence of functions is $$ f_{n} = \sqrt{x + \frac{1}{n}} $$
which uniformly convergences to $f(x)= \sqrt x $ which is not differentiable at $x=0$

Comment: :) and it's more simple, how did you find the sequence? I mean how did you come up with this?

Comment: I sketched  several curves of sequences of smooth functions which eventually approaches to a non differentiable function, I only considered horizontal translations (left-right) then I figured out too many examples! and picked the one that can be written in the simple formula like $\sqrt x$

Comment:  definitely a clever way of thinking, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Take $A=2.$ Then the functions

$$f_n(x) = (1/n +(x-1/2)^2)^{1/2}$$

are in $B(2)$ and converge uniformly to $|x-1/2|$ on $[0,1].$ Since $|x-1/2|\not \in C^1,$ $B(2)$ is not closed.